# .NET EF - dividing a byte field results an int instead of double

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Interesting one.

See the following Entity Framework query:

```
Entities.Select(x => new
{
    x.ExperienceMonths,
    Calculated = (x.ExperienceMonths > 0 ? x.ExperienceMonths / 12 : 0)
})
```

The column `ExperienceMonths` is a `tinyint` in the database, which means it's a `byte` in the EF model.

I'd expect `Calculated` column to be a `double` (`float`), since we're dividing a number, but no matter what I do it always ends up an `int` and any `decimal` portion of the result is simply removed, so for ex 3.7 ends up 3.

Is there a way to force EF to convert the result somehow to `double`? Adding a (`double`) cast before the division expression breaks at runtime.

Using EF5.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to use `Convert.ToDouble()`?

Comment: Have you tried: `x.ExperienceMonths * 1.0m / 12.0m : 0.0m` - what you're currently doing is an **integer** division and works as designed and as expected.

Comment: All is true and LINQPad approves all casts that are suggested here, but still, when running in the app against the DB (meaning the SQL provider converts this legal LINQ expression to SQL) that's when it fails. And the error is always something along the lines of: Internal .NET Framework Data Provider error 1004, 0, Unresolvable Var used in Command: VarType=Column, Id=1174.

Comment: So which sql provider is this? An explicit cast to double (by `(double)`) works with sql server and EF.

Comment: @GertArnold: Yes, I was so sure I tried that cast! And yes, it does work! Too many hours of work.. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried:

```
Calculated = (x.ExperienceMonths > 0 ? ((double)x.ExperienceMonths) / 12 : 0)
```

And it worked fine

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I have no idea how I missed this. I guess too many trials and errors.. I was sure I tried that cast...  :)

Thanks again!